# Transpose to object but without values, yet

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I'm importing esxtop data from an ESXi host. The import gives me two sets of data. The first is the list of all the fields that I will be getting data from. The second is data in those fields.

The fields list is like this:

```
|SchedGroup|GroupID|GroupName|IsValid|IsVM|VMName|TimerPeriod|CPUAllocMin|CPUAllocMax|
```

I converted this into a Selected.System.String named $Headercols:

```
header                
------                
SchedGroup            
GroupID               
GroupName             
IsValid               
IsVM                  
VMName                
TimerPeriod           
CPUAllocMin           
CPUAllocMax
```

But I actually need it to be in columns, instead of rows. Because later on I want to add "records" / "rows" containing the data. I tried using converting to columns using add-member, but that needs a name and a value, but I don't know the value yet.

The example here only has a few rows, but this grows to 33 rows, so I'd rather fill them in a loop instead of addressing each one specifically.

Later on I will be receiving the data like this:

```
|SchedGroup|13567824|vm.4430541|1|1|BJLDC002|10416|0|-1|
|SchedGroup|12883482|vm.4316334|1|1|VCDJAGTEST|15260|0|-1|
|SchedGroup|13558449|vm.4429332|1|1|BJLADF02|1000|0|-1|
```

(Example has 3 rows, each one VM, but it can be many more rows with VMs.)
I know how to split the rows into separate values, but just as with the headers, I wouldn't know how to expand the object.

All examples I google are immediately adding name and value, I can't seem to get my head around how I should work with that.

Comment: That's because most formatting and export cmdlets don't expect you to "create columns" - you just create the objects, and cmdlets like `Format-Table` and `Export-Csv` will _infer_ logical column names from the properties of the objects. You're trying to solve a non-existing problem

Comment: Ok, so is the way I'm addressing this wrong? How can I end up with an object that looks like this:
SchedGroup,GroupID,GroupName,IsValid,IsVM,VMName,TimerPeriod
SchedGroup,13567824,vm.4430541,1,1,BJLDC002,10416
SchedGroup,12883482,vm.4316334,1,1,VCDJAGTEST,15260
SchedGroup,13558449,vm.4429332,1,1,BJLADF02,1000

Comment: That's just a csv tabular format. Just replace the `|` with ',' using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I actually need it to be in columns, instead of rows.

You're getting ahead of yourself - "columns" and "rows" relate to how we might *format* (or *display*) the data - but right now we need to import and *parse* the data somehow.

I would suggest trimming the leading and trailing `|`'s, at which point we can treat the data set as a CSV (with `|` instead of `,` as the separator - a PSV?):

```
# Read header list and split into individual strings
$headerString = Get-Content .\path\to\headers.txt |Select -First 1
$headers = $headerString.Split('|', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

# Read data set, remove the leading and trailing pipes
$dataSetRaw = (Get-Content .\path\to\data.txt) -replace '^\||\|$'

# Convert to structured objects
$data = $dataSetRaw |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header $headers
```

`ConvertFrom-Csv` will create one object per record, at which point you'll find most formatting cmdlets do exactly what you expect:

```
PS ~> $data |Format-Table

SchedGroup GroupID  GroupName  IsValid IsVM VMName     TimerPeriod CPUAllocMin CPUAllocMax
---------- -------  ---------  ------- ---- ------     ----------- ----------- -----------
SchedGroup 13567824 vm.4430541 1       1    BJLDC002   10416       0           -1
SchedGroup 12883482 vm.4316334 1       1    VCDJAGTEST 15260       0           -1
SchedGroup 13558449 vm.4429332 1       1    BJLADF02   1000        0           -1
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. When working with your solution I first didn't get it to work, because I ignored the "[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries" part. I was convinced I could leave it out because all data is always received without spaces. But turns out the convertfrom-csv then fails on the $headers. After adding the "[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries", it worked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment...

```
'|SchedGroup|GroupID|GroupName|IsValid|IsVM|VMName|TimerPeriod|CPUAllocMin|CPUAllocMax|' -replace '\|', ','  -replace '^,|,\s*$'
# Results
<#
SchedGroup,GroupID,GroupName,IsValid,IsVM,VMName,TimerPeriod,CPUAllocMin,CPUAllocMax
#>
```

Yet, you say your data is coming in this way...

```
SchedGroup,13567824,vm.4430541,1,1,BJLDC002,10416 
SchedGroup,12883482,vm.4316334,1,1,VCDJAGTEST,15260 
SchedGroup,13558449,vm.4429332,1,1,BJLADF02,1000
```

...then just import it and assign headers.

```
$Headers = @('|SchedGroup|GroupID|GroupName|IsValid|IsVM|VMName|TimerPeriod|CPUAllocMin|CPUAllocMax|' -replace '\|', ','  -replace '^,|,\s*$')
Import-Csv -Path 'SomeFilePath' -Header $Headers
```

Comment: Nice. It's a bit unclear from the question, but I got the impression that the values come in the same format, ie. `|A|B|C|`

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen... Roger that, as when you copy his record data to notepad, it's not rows, but all one line. Yet, I also assumed, it was a posting mistake. Either way, what you an i provided should be more than enough to get the OP where they need to be.

Comment: My data is not coming from a CSV but from this:
$esxtopCounters = $serviceView.ExecuteSimpleCommand("CounterInfo")

But you pointed me in the right way. Together with @MathiasR.Jessen 's reply I was able to solve it.

Comment: Good to know we got you the needed lightbulb moment. Take Care/Stay Safe out there.